# leaflet popup window does not perform correctly on HTTPS and working better on HTTP

Tags: javascript, https, leaflet

I created a map with leaflet and i add a pop up window [with HTTP] [enter image description here][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfbfd.png
so when the user click on the county it should show up a pop up window has some info, when i add the map to my website the pop up window niw showing at the right bottom of the screen, anyone know how to fix this issue ??
[with HTTPS][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVIST.png

here is my code:-

```js
function countriesStyle(feature){
 return {
  stroke: '#179989',
  fill: 'brightgreen',
  preferCanvas: false,
  fillColor : '#ccc',
  weight : 0.5,
  opacity : 1,
  dashArray : 3,
  fillOpacity : 1,
  dashArray: null,
  dashOffset: null
 }
}
//creating a new map
var map = L.map('map').setView([37.4, -120], 5.8);

//create a new Geojason layer and set it up to basins var ....
var basinsLayer = L.geoJson(ca, basins).addTo(map);
basinsLayer.setStyle({fillColor :'#ccc'});
function testStyle(feature, layer) {
 function changeURL() {
    //get the URL and change the location.search to Basin_Name
       var theURL = "https://gx.otdev3.com/basin/antelope-valley";
       return  theURL.replace("antelope-valley", feature.properties.Basin_Name);
 }
 // Basin Number of the Basins Pages ...
 if(feature.properties.Basin_Number == "1-001" || 
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "1-002.01" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "1-002.02" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "1-003" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "1-004" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "1-005" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "1-052" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "1-055.01" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "2-001" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "2-002.02" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "2-009.01" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "2-009.02" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "2-009.04" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "2-010" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "2-032" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "2-033" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "2-037" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "2-038" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "2-039" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-001" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-002.01" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-002.02" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-003.01" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-003.02" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-003.03" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-003.04" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-004.01" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-004.02" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-004.04" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-004.05" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-004.06" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-004.09" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-004.10" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-004.11" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-007" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-008" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-009" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-012" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-013" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-014" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-015" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-016" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-025" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-026" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "3-027" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "4-002" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "4-003.01" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "4-004.02" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "4-004.05" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "4-004.06" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "4-004.07" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "4-006" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "4-007" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "4-008" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "4-011.01" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "4-012" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "4-013" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-004" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-006.01" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-006.02" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-006.03" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-006.04" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-006.05" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-006.06" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-012.01" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-014" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-021.50" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-021.51" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-021.52" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-021.53" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-021.54" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-021.55" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-021.56" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-021.57" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-021.58" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-021.59" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-021.60" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-021.61" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-021.62" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-021.63" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-021.60" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-021.61" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-021.62" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-021.63" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-021.64" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-021.65" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-021.66" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-021.67" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-021.69" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-022.01" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-022.02" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-022.03" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-022.04" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-022.05" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-022.06" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-022.07" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-022.08" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-022.09" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-022.10" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-022.11" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-022.12" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-022.13" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-022.14" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-022.15" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-022.16" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-022.18" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "5-029" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "6-005.01" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "6-012.01" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "6-012.02" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "6-044" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "6-054" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "7-005" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "7-021.01" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "7-021.02" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "7-021.03" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "7-021.04" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "7-022" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "7-024.01" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "7-024.02" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "7-025" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "7-028" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "7-029" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "7-030" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "7-033" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "7-034" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "7-035" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "7-036" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "7-037" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "7-038" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "7-039" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "7-061" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "8-001" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "8-002.01" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "8-002.03" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "8-002.07" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "8-002.08" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "8-002.09" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "8-004.01" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "8-004.02" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "8-005" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "8-009" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "9-007" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "9-010" ||
  feature.properties.Basin_Number == "9-015"){
  // only for the existing basin pages 
  layer.setStyle({fillColor :'#1FC18F'});
  layer.bindPopup(
   '<p>' + 
   feature.properties.Basin_Name + '</p>' +
   "<p> Basin Number: "+ feature.properties.Basin_Number + "</p>" +    
   "<a class='basin_link' href='" + changeURL()+ "'>Take me to that Basin</a>");
 }else {
  layer.bindPopup("<h5'>This basin is not subject to SGMA</h5>");
 }
 // change the URL
 $('.basin_link').attr('href', changeURL());
};
  
//get basin geoJson file and add it to the map
L.geoJson(basins, {
  onEachFeature: testStyle,
  style: countriesStyle
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing all your code, i would say the leaflet CSS file is missing or corrupted, or you may be overwriting it in some way when its live.

EG, you may be setting `.leaflet-popup-content` to `position: absolute;`

If you can provide a working example on something like jsfiddle that show's the issue i could have a better look and see if i can find the actual reason.

UPDATE:
on further thought, you may be calling the leaflet.css over http instead of https, some browsers will block all http content when viewing the site in https.

you could fix this by calling a https copy of the CSS.

Comment: you were absolutely right!! Thanks alot, I appreciate your help.